# Autofac Open Generic Decorator with multiple interface causes circular dependency resolving

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, decorator, autofac

I have the following interfaces :

```
public interface ICommandHandler<T>
{
    void Handle(T command);
}

public class TransactionalCommandHandlerDecorator<T> : ICommandHandler<T>
{
    private readonly ICommandHandler<T> _handler;
    public TransactionalCommandHandlerDecorator(ICommandHandler<T> handler)
    {
        _handler = handler;
    }
    public void Handle(T command)
    {
    }
}
```

and I have a concrete class which implementing two command handlers :

```
public class Handler : ICommandHandler<CreateLocation>
                        ,ICommandHandler<ModifyLocation>
{
    public void Handle(CreateLocation command)
    {

    }

    public void Handle(ModifyLocation command)
    {
    }
}
```

and I have a registration as following :

```
 builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
            .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(ICommandHandler<>))
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

    builder.RegisterGenericDecorator(typeof(TransactionalCommandHandlerDecorator<>), typeof(ICommandHandler<>));
```

Resolving 'Handler' class causes autofac to circularly resolving decorater and handler in an infinite loop which causes a StackOverflowException. if I a change 'Handler' to implement only one interface, then it will works without problem.

any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: Seems like a bug to me. I wanted to propose to report this on the Autofac issue page, but apparently, you [already done that](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/988) :)

Comment: Did you try excluding the decorator from the assembly scanning so it doesn't try to decorate itself?

Comment: yes. i excluded the 'TransactionalCommandHandlerDecorator' from the assembly scanning using following code:

.Where(a=> !typeof(TransactionalCommandHandlerDecorator<>).IsAssignableFrom(a))

but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/988) and will be addressed in a future release of Autofac. The fix looks like it will require a breaking change to another part of the API so will need to be released as part of `v5.0`.

In the meantime, one way to work around the issue is creating separate registrations.

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<Handler>().As<ICommandHandler<CreateLocation>>();
builder.RegisterType<Handler>().As<ICommandHandler<ModifyLocation>>();
builder.RegisterGenericDecorator(typeof(TransactionalCommandHandlerDecorator<>), typeof(ICommandHandler<>));
var container = builder.Build();

var instance = container.Resolve<ICommandHandler<CreateLocation>>();
```